Does it ever make sense to have a one-to-one obligatory relationship in a relational database?
To illustrate what I mean, imagine a group of students and a group of professors in some kind of a traineeship. Every professor is to mentor one student and every student has to be mentored by one and only one professor. Thus, we have an obligatory one-to-one relationship.
Let's furthermore say that every student has a studentID (primary key), name and a phone number, and every professor has a professorID, name and a phone number. In this scenario, would it make sense to have a single table where you list all the attributes for a single entity (that is, studentID, their name, phone number, the ID of their mentor and then their name and phone number)?
My first thought is that this kind of scheme breaks the 3rd normalization form, as the professor's name and phone number are dependent on the professorID, and that perhaps splitting the table into two, having a Professor table that contains the professor's name and phone number and putting the professorID into the student table as a foreign key is the proper way of going about it. At the same time, since it's an obligatory one-to-one relationship, would that even matter?

This particular relationship might be one-to-one at the moment, but may very likely not be in the future. It's very common for a professor to mentor multiple students. Such requirement is likely to occure in the future. Do not believe it won't ever change. Additionally there can be various other unexpected situations, like a student mentoring other student. Why not? Therefore separate tables and foreign keys sounds like better choice.

Do you also plan to use this software next year, when the same professors have a new batch of mentees?

Your example might be 1:1 at any given moment, but it is N:M temporally, i.e. the students might change mentors, and the professors might change mentees, especially as students graduate. Reassociating a foreign key is a much more sensible operation to represent this than rewriting half of each row.

I agree with @freakish's main point, but "student mentoring student" is a bridge too far as something that has to be accounted for. The definition of a mentor is a person who mentors. Therefore, this person (who is also a student) acts as a mentor. Whether or not mentor/student rely on some kind of reusable hierarchy in order to reuse their personal details is an implementation detail, but doesn't invalidate the notion that for the purpose of modeling the act of mentoring a "mentor" is well defined regardless of this person also being a student in other scenarios.

This implies every time a student transfers or leaves school, you must fire the corresponding professor.  This sounds absurd, but I think this is because the 1:1 example is not truly 1:1.  How many situations are truly 1:1?

It sounds like you are mostly asking about relational theory, but I will point out that you don't actually say that's the only case you're concerned with; and there can be pragmatic reasons to split a table into two tables with a 1:1 relationship (e.g. to fix specific performance issues).

Normalization aside, if you are asking about storing prof and student data together, in a single table, then wouldn’t that complicate swapping mentors, for example?

If there always is a strict 1:1 relationship between teacher and student then it is not a violation of 3rd normal form to have both in the same table.
One-to-one relationships in a single table is not problematic from a normalization perspective. It just means you have two unique ID's in the same table and have to select one of them as primary key. Then you can add a unique constraint to the other.
Normalization issues arise when you have a one-to-many relationship in the same table. E.g. if a professor can mentor multiple students then you cannot have professors and students in the same table without duplicating data. So you would need to break it into two separate tables.
Having a strict 1:1 relationship between two separate tables is possible but leads to some unnecessary complexity. You can enforce the 1:1 relationship between the tables by having a unique key in each table be a foreign key to the the other table. But this makes it more difficult to insert and delete rows, since it must happen at the same time. Depending on the database system, it might be possible trough an updatable view or might require a transaction. In any case it is more complex and doesn't really provide any benefit, assuming the relationship really is strict 1.1
But normalization is just one aspect of database design. Just as important is the data model should realistically support the requirements of the application. And while I don't know your requirements, I suspect the strict 1:1 relationship is too strong an assumption for a real-world system.
For example you could have a teacher retiring causing a new teacher to take over the mentee or a student dropping out causing a teacher to be without a mentee for a while. Another concern is you can't keep historical records: If a professors gets a new student to mentor, all data related to the previous student will have to be overwritten.
More generally, a database model is always a simplified model of reality. For example a person might have multiple addresses and multiple phone numbers, but in most systems it is perfectly fine to just record one. You should not try to model "the real world" realistically. But you should model what is necessary for your application to work.

When modeling your relationships, ask can X have just one of Y.  For example, a car only has 1 license plate.  This is an example of strict 1 to 1 relationship.  Can a mentor have multiple mentees?  Can a mentee have multiple mentors?  One can always start with looser (multiple) relations even if just one.  But if starting with strict, it will be an effort to refactor into multiples.  So, make sure it is truly a strict 1:1.

@JonRaynor I disagree. It is much easier to loosen a constraint than it is to tighten one, because in the latter case there might be existing data which violates the constraint you want to add. It is a pretty simple operation to split one table into two, but it might be impossible to go the other way given existing data.

With 2 tables a combination of a NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY and UNIQUE constraints, can enforce the relationship is 1 to 0|1  - it is necessary to insert into one table before the other, so you can't do better than that with 2 tables. Therefore you won't ever run into the 1 to many situation, if you need to convert to a single table. Although this conversion might require some nullable fields to handle the 1 to 0 case.

When there is a strict one to one there is a column in a table.  Going back to the car, license plate.  Table Car, Table License Plate.  Joiner Table Car_LicensePlate.  I can have zero, one, or many plates assigned to one car or vice versa.    I can always add another column to car to support a second license plate.  But if starting with looser requirements (joiner table) I can support 0, 1, or many.   However, that is more complex than just a single column in a table, so certainly that is the simpler approach if there is a true 1 to 1.  The joiner table eliminates all nulls as well.


Does it ever make sense to have a one-to-one obligatory relationship in a relational database?

If both sides are exactly 1 (not zero/optional), then in my opinion no. A hard 1-1 relationship suggests that these should just represent a single table entry (in a single table)

Every professor is to mentor one student and every student has to be mentored by one and only one professor. Thus, we have an obligatory one-to-one relationship.

That's not a 1-1 relationship though, invalidating the question in the title.
What you're implying here is that a mentor will only ever mentor one student one time, and will never mentor again. You will also not have this mentor in your system until you know for a fact who they will be mentoring.
At the same time you're saying the same thing about a student. They will only be mentored once, then never again, and you will not enter this student's details before their mentor is known.
If your assertions are true (which I highly doubt they are), then this goes back to my initial point: there's no point listing a mentor and a student separately. You only intend to create these at the exact same time, and will never break their relationship. Therefore this can be expressed as a single entry, there is no value from spreading this across two or more tables.
Much more likely, you are misrepresenting your relationship. What seems much more likely is that you have a collection of mentors (created before they start mentoring), a collection of students (created before they are mentored), and then you will generate a mentoring session, and it is this session which has precisely one mentor and one student.
At the same time, one mentor can mentor multiple times, both mentoring the same student repeatedly or mentoring multiple students (but always one per session). At the same time, one student can be mentored multiple times, both by the same mentor repeatedly, or by different mentors (but always one per session).
It may be true that in a given time period, the relationship is exclusive (i.e. this year, mentor A will mentor student B, and neither of them will have other concurrent sessions), but that is a business requirement, not a data normalization requirement. These are two very different concepts.
What about next year? What if, for whatever reasons, their mentoring ends abruptly and both of them get reassigned? If you model this as a 1-1 relationship, all of these edge cases become impossible to model.
The more pragmatic interpretation of your scenario represents a very different relationship:

We can argue whether you consider session to be the cross table between student/mentor, or whether you think of it as its own entity with two required FKs (one to mentor, one to student).
Personally, I only call it a cross table if it contains nothing but the FKs (and potentially a PK of its own). Otherwise, I call it an entity on its own. But this is subjective.
This invalidates the premise of your question, since you're not actually dealing with a 1-1 relationship.

There is also the rather comical situation of how the student and professor apply/are interviewed for the position - do they interview in pairs so that they can both be entered into the system at the same time...

It is true that with an obligatory one-to-one relationship, there is no structural reason to require separate tables. You can simply add all columns in one table, and that is sufficient to store the data.
There can however be other reasons in practice to split the tables.
One is to conceptually organise what would otherwise be a large number of columns in one table. This doesn't apply to your example as given, but I have certainly seen examples of tables that had too much variety of data which was conceptually disparate.
Another is to control permissions/access to the tables differently.
A third can be to control which columns are packed together in the underlying physical storage - this can sometimes have performance implications due to access or locking patterns.  For example, splitting the columns across multiple tables, means that a single row lock now only locks some of the columns, and columns falling into different tables can be updated concurrently and independently.
A fourth is when readapting the database, and for whatever reason adding columns directly to an existing table is considered too disruptive, so another supplementary table is bolted on.
I wouldn't say any of these cases occur very commonly, but it does demonstrate that there can be many practical, performance, maintenance and management concerns involved in real database work, which can go well beyond designing the basic relational model for storing the data.

A fifth is when you need to update student-teacher relationships. With separate tables you just swap some foreign keys, but with a single table you have to swap many columns.

For 1 and to an extend 2 the usage of views might offer the same or even more benefit than splitting the table. I'd say nr. 3 is the strongest and most likely to occur reason to keep data from an obligatory 1:1 relationship in separate tables.

First, let me get this out of the way: concepts like student & teacher are roles for a person, not subclasses of person — one person can be both a student and a teacher; student & teacher are ephemeral roles compared with being a person for life.
Next, I think of 1:1 or 1:N relationships as an optimization on N:M relationships, which I therefore start with and only perform optimization when convinced that it is appropriate and that it matters for performance.  (Sure we can require that N>=1 and also M>=1.)
A person can have multiple phone numbers, multiple addresses, multiple contact methods, multiple degrees, multiple mentors, multiple mentees, etc..
The mentor-mentee relationship can be formalized as an entity in it own right, which may carry additional information regarding that relationship (an agreement id#, a start date, a subject matter, preferred methods of contact, schedule, an end date, etc..).

"I think of 1:1 or 1:N relationships as an optimization on N:M relationships" - strongly disagree. They are different structures representing different information. Turning a proper N:M relationship into a 1:1 relationship would imply data loss. "Optimization" implies an improvement in performance without data loss.

@JacquesB, yes, in many cases, it is not appropriate rather than being a (possibly premature) optimization.

@JacquesB well, 1:1 and 1:n relationships can always also be modeled as N:M relationship. In a sense 1:1 relationships are a special case of 1:n relationships just like 1:n relationships are a special case of n:m relationships. You are just putting upper and lower limits on N or M. And this limit is in this case "1". If your N:M relationship turns out to be always 1 to 1 then you can optimize that relationship to a 1:1 and get an improvement in performance without any data loss. So they are "special case optimizations".

It might make sense in environments where high data security is paramount.
For example, in case of your student/teacher relationship a teaching assistant may have limited access to the student table only (and likely only a subset of that table) and have no access to the teacher table at all. That's easier to handle than field level security where you'd need to set permissions for every field in a table separately, rather than per table.
Another example is auditing. Maybe you want auditing (which can be a disk space and CPU expensive operation) only on some of your data, not on the rest (to save cost). Separating that data that needs to go into the audit log into a separate table with a 1-1 link to the parent table enables that.
Or you have a system where some fields are optional for retrieval but very expensive to retrieve. Think BLOBs. Putting those into a separate table and having a foreign key to that table into that child table can speed up data retrieval (and reduce network load).

In purest theory, if your situation is EXACTLY as you stated, and there is ZERO chance that it (or the requirements around it) will change: No.
But you may have noticed there a a lot of conditionals in the preceding sentence.
Perhaps you are compiling a database of "Odd professors who had lived a long time ago and only have had exactly one odd student each (who in turn only had exactly one mentor), including information on those students"...
Since the likelihood of that is slim, I'd argue that this is - while possibly not yet a violation in the technical sense - something that will become one the very moment you start thinking about those students and professors as individuals (which may already be hinted at by saying that studentID and professorID are unique keys) instead of a horrible inseparable professor-student-mentor amalgamation.

The best approach is to separate the data into three entities: a student table, a teacher table, and a student-teacher pairing table.
There are a few reasons to do this:

Rule of least surprise. If someone else comes to maintain the database they will be surprised to see student and teacher data bundled together in a single row.
Simplify logging. This kind of data is often stored in a "slowly changing dimension" format (google this if you aren't familiar with the term). You might want to be able to delineate student data updates from teacher updates. That's much easier to do if you separated the tables.
Reduce redundancy when updates are made. If you are storing the data as a slowly changing dimension, then you will need to duplicate all the student data even in cases where none of it changed because the update was linked to the teacher.
Your baseline assumption is bad. If natural language suggests the data belongs to multiple entities then it is highly probable that they are not locked in a permanent 1-to-1 relationship. If you put the data into a single table you're setting yourself up for extra work at a later stage when a new requirement breaks the relationship. Fixing the database tables is easy but you might have a built a load of other code on top of it by the time you discover the requirement.


one additional aspect you might add is data portability and security, you might need to export all professors (easier if split) or only grant access for someone to the student  or just the professor data etc.

Normal form has no problem with the teacher and student sharing a row when there is a 1 to 1 relationship. However, are there other tables?
When you put teacher and student in the same row what you've lost is the ability to refer to a teacher separately from a student.
@flater makes an effective argument about how that breaks down over time if the teacher ever mentors another student. However, even without that, other tables can have a need to refer to them separately. What about payroll? What about security badges? Other things may need a unique identifier for each of them.
Don't design in a vacuum. Look beyond these two and think about what you're doing to your other needs with this choice.

Your example might be 1:1 at any given moment, but it is N:M temporally, i.e. the students might change mentors, and the professors might change mentees, especially as students graduate.
If you have separate tables for professors and students, such a change means rewriting some foreign keys. If you have them in the same table, it means overwriting one half of the fields.
Also, these two entities probably don't exist in isolation. There are probably other entities referencing them. For example, classes might be taught by a professor, and clubs might be led by a student. These other entities probably want to reference the entities by primary key, but a table has only one primary key. If the professor's ID is the primary key of the combined table, then does the Club.leader_id field reference the professor, and thus is led by "the mentee of Prof. Snape"? If mentor assignments change, do you have to update all clubs to reference the new mentor?

One reason to "split a table" would be performance. This is already mentioned in  jwenting's and Steve's answers. More compact physical layout, perhaps more compact indices.
In particular, one of the tables may be small enough to be kept in memory, thus speeding up queries.

Having two tables would require a join to get at the same information, which might be slower than scanning a single table. But in any case, for a realistically sized school the number of professors and students would be low enough that query performance isn't a concern.

@JacquesB Indeed. But if for some queries you need only the info in one of the tables, then it may be beneficial to split. Say, into "frequently queried" and "rarely queried". Anyway, my answer considers the scenario just an example to illustrate OP's question.

Although not the case here, it might also make sense if the two tables represent different facets of the same thing. E.g. a customer and an account might always be 1:1, but the former is focused on contact information, and the latter on financial details.

After considering the title ony, an alternative reason to have a mandatory one-to-one relationship could be a legacy system having one of the main tables (lets call it Project) bursting with columns added over the years. At some point it might make sense (among other solutions) to create a new table (for example ProjectSettings) for the bloat to continue there without affecting existing system too much. :D

Or different facets of the same thing, not necessarily for legacy reasons. E.g your Project might contain a bunch of publicly-visible information, while ProjectSettings has the bits which are more security-sensitive (or just less interesting). Essentially, two entities which are tightly-coupled, but nevertheless not the same entity.

No not really.
If you have an enforced 1:1 relationship between two tables it's just the same as adding more columns to the first table.
You could have a 1:1/0 relationship where you want optional columns. eg
Person
Id, type
1, professor
2, student

Professor
Id, role
1, chemistry

Student
Id, Grade
2, B+

